# What's the range of $a$ when $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\log_e n)^{2012}}{n^a} $ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

What's the range of $a$ when $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\log_e n)^{2012}}{n^a} $ is convergent?

Ratio test doesn't work. By root test I think a>0 is enough, but the answer is a>1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **PRIMER:**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1<x}\tag{P1}$$
>
> for $x>0$.  Now, using $\log(x^b)=b\log(x)$, then we see from $(P1)$ that for $b>0$,
>
> $$\log(x)\le \frac{x^b-1}{b}<\frac{x^b}{b}\tag {P2}$$

---

Note from $(P2)$, with $x=n$, that $\log(n)\le \frac{n^b-1}{b}<\frac{n^b}{b}$ for all $b>0$.  Therefore,

$$\frac{\log^{2012}(n)}{n^a}<\frac{n^{2012b}}{bn^a} \tag 1$$

The inequality in $(1)$ is valid for all $b>0$ including those values of $b$ such that $a-2012b>1$.  Therefore, taking $b<\frac{a-1}{2012}$, we see that the series converges by the "$p$ test" for $a>1$.

---

Just as a numerical example, suppose $a=1.001$.  Then, we can take $b<\frac{1}{2,012,000}$, say $b=\frac{1}{4,012,000}$, and thus

$$\frac{\log^{2012}(n)}{n^{1.001}}<\left(\frac{4,012,000}{n^{1.0005}}\right)$$

And the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{4,012,000}{n^{1.0005}}\right)$ converges.

---

Now, if $a=1$ the series diverges.  We can use the integral test.  Simply write

$$\int_1^L \frac{\log^{2012}(x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\log^{2013}(L)}{2013}\to \infty$$

The integral test shows that the series diverges for $a=1$

If $a<1$, then the series diverges by comparison with the harmonic series since for $a<1$

$$\frac{\log^{2012}(n)}{n^a}\ge \frac{1}{n}$$

---

> Putting it all together, we see that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log^{2012}(n)}{n^a}$ converges for all $a>1$ and diverges for all $a\le 1$.

Comment: It may be worth noting that in essence, the behaviour of $\frac{\log^b(n)}{n^a}$ is the same for every $b$ i.e. it depends only on $a$. Only if $a = 1$ then $b$ may make the sum converge if $b \le -1$.

Comment: @Ant The series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\log^b(n)}{n}$ converges for $b<-1$, but not for $b=-1$.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. But $\displaystyle \log(n)\le \frac{n^b-1}{b}<\frac{n^b}{b}$ took me some time to prove and I don't think I can think of this inequality if this problem shows up on a timed exam. Is it a fact that I should remember? I still wonder why the root test doesn't work. By root test we can get $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{2012}{a} \times \frac {1}{n^{\frac{a}{2012}}} =0$  for a>0

Comment: Hank, I've added a primer that explains the origin of the inequality in question.  I would try and remember $\log(x)\le x-1$ and $\log(x^b)=b\log(x)$ since these are quite important and often used. -Mark

Comment: The root test doesn't work here since $$\limsup_{n\to \infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=\limsup_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{\log^{2012}(n)}{n^a}\right|^{1/n}=\limsup_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{\log^{2012/n}(n)}{n^{a/n}}\right|=1$$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in using the root test. Thanks a lot! It's very kind of  you to give such a thorough answer.

Comment: @hank Hank, you're welcome.  It's my pleasure!